# Running an Akka Cluster with EC2 and Docker. Nodes aren't registered in akka-cluster

Tags: scala, docker, amazon-ec2, akka-cluster

I implemented the following sample of the akka-cluster system, please see below diagram:

```
                                 ┌────host_D:3000────┐
                        ┌───────▶│    ....           │  
                        │      ┌────host_C:3000────┐ │  
 ┌────host_A:2551────┐  │ ┌───▶│                   │ │
 │                   │──┘ │  ┌────host_B:3000────┐ │ │  
 │┌─────────────────┐│────┘  │┌─────────────────┐│ │ │  
 ││   MasterActor   ││──────▶││   WorkerActor   ││ │─┘
 │└─────────────────┘│       │└─────────────────┘│─┘
 └───────────────────┘       └───────────────────┘
```

The `MasterActor` and `WorkerActor` are implemented in separated `sbt-modules` and started with using scalatra-servlets. So an actor system is created in `ServletContextListener` when a particular sbt module is deployed.

The `MasterActor` and `WorkerActor` are subscribed to the cluster events (such as MemberJoin/Up/etc). The `WorkerActor` can be scaled on the different nodes. And the following restrictions for the ports are used:

- `2551` - for the MasterActor's cluster node
- `3000` - for the WorkerActor's cluster node

I need to focus on cluster-events only. Because the following details were omitted in this topic:

- detecting of seed-nodes (they calculated by [EC2 client](https://github.com/chrisloy/akka-ec2))
- sending messages from MasterActor to workers (they are sent by some load balancer).

This works successfully on my local machine (and with using virtual machines under VirtualBox). But I've faced with the issues when I deployed on EC2/docker.
For example, I use two EC2 hosts with the following IP: `10.x.x.A` and `10.x.x.B`. The my project can be deployed in EC2 in the following ways:

1. `MasterActor` module at `10.x.x.A` and `WorkerActor` module at `10.x.x.B`
2. vice versa
3. the modules are deployed in the same host.

I consider the way#1 when modules are deployed in the different hosts. Since I don't known which IP will be used for the `MasterActor` then I reserve a seed-nodes for each node. According to the above restrictions for the ports. Please see below diagram which illustrates the my infrastructure and akka-cluster configuration.

```
┌──[ec2@10.x.x.A]─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                             │
│  > ifconfig                                                 │ 
│    eth0 10.x.x.A                                            │
│    docker0 172.17.0.1                                       │ 
│                                                             │ 
│                                                             │ 
│  ┌─────[docker:172.17.x.d1]──────────────────────────────┐  │
│  │ > ifconfig                       ┌─────────────────┐  │  │
│  │   eth0    172.17.x.d1            │   MasterActor   │  │  │
│  │                                  └─────────────────┘  │  │
│  │ ClusterSystem {                                       │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname      = "10.x.x.A"    │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.port          = "2551"        │  │
│  │   akka.cluster.roles                  = ["master"]    │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-hostname = "172.17.x.d1" │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-port     = "2552"        │  │
│  │   akka.cluster.seed-nodes = [                         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.A:2551",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.A:3000",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.B:2551",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.B:3000" ]        │  │
│  │ }                                                     │  │
│  │                                                       │  │
│  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘   


┌──[ec2@10.x.x.B]─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                             │
│  > ifconfig                                                 │ 
│    eth0 10.x.x.B                                            │
│    docker0 172.17.0.1                                       │ 
│                                                             │ 
│                                                             │ 
│  ┌─────[docker:172.17.x.d2]──────────────────────────────┐  │
│  │ > ifconfig                       ┌─────────────────┐  │  │
│  │   eth0    172.17.x.d2            │   WorkerActor   │  │  │
│  │                                  └─────────────────┘  │  │
│  │ ClusterSystem {                                       │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname      = "10.x.x.B"    │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.port          = "3000"        │  │
│  │   akka.cluster.roles                  = ["worker"]    │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-hostname = "172.17.x.d2" │  │
│  │   akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-port     = "2552"        │  │
│  │   akka.cluster.seed-nodes = [                         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.A:2551",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.A:3000",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.B:2551",         │  │
│  │     "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.x.x.B:3000" ]        │  │
│  │ }                                                     │  │
│  │                                                       │  │
│  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Into the each EC2 instance I illustrated the result of `ifconfig` command. The same was illustrated into each docker.
For akka-cluster configuration I used this [manual](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.8/remoting.html?language=scala#akka-behind-nat-or-in-a-docker-container):

**The main issue**: the `MasterActor` node is started and registered itself in the akka-cluster successfully. But the `WorkerActor`is started but doesn't registered in the akka-cluster.

**The main questions**: is this a correct configuration for the my cluster system? Are there any mistakes?

Also I've found some issue which can be connected with the main issue:

1. Can't ping from `10.x.x.A` to `10.x.x.B` and vice versa

Comment: Fancy diagrams!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was connected with hosts and ports availability:

`Can't ping from 10.x.x.A to 10.x.x.B and vice versa`

Now cluster works successfully.

Comment: I have a question what does this cluster do in your scenario are you running a http api or huge computations in akka cluster ? why not you choosed Flink or Spark for your use case ?