# Akka-cluster holds and keeps storing wrong info about membership on EC2/docker

Tags: scala, docker, amazon-ec2, akka-cluster

Environment: `scala-2.11.x`, `akka-2.5.9`

There are two hosts on EC2: `H1` and `H2`.
There are tree modules of sbt-project: `master`, `client` and `worker`.
Each module implement akka-cluster node, which subscribes to a cluster events and logs them. Also each node logs a cluster state every 1 minute (for debug). The following ports are used for cluster-nodes:`master: 2551`, `worker: 3000`, `client: 5000`

The project available at [github](https://github.com/zx80live/akka-cluster-template)

The more details about infrastructure: [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628656/running-an-akka-cluster-with-ec2-and-docker-nodes-arent-registered-in-akka-clu)

A module can be redeployed in `H1` or `H2` randomly.

There is a strange behavior of the akka-cluster. When one of nodes (for example `worker`) is redeployed. The following steps illustrate a history of deploying:

The initial state - when `worker` is deployed on `H1` and `master` and `client` are deployed on `H2`

```
----[state-of-deploying-0]---  
H1 = [worker]
H2 = [master, client]

cluster status:    // cluster works correctly
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H1:3000, status = Up)
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H2:2551, status = Up)
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H2:5000, status = Up)
----------------
```

After that the `worker` module has been redeployed on host `H2`

```
----[state-of-deploying-1]---  
H1 = [-]
H2 = [master, client, worker (Redeployed)]

cluster status:    // WRONG cluster state!
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H1:3000, status = Up) // ???
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H2:2551, status = Up)
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H2:3000, status = WeaklyUp)
  Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H2:5000, status = Up)
----------------
```

The above situation happens occasionally. In this case a cluster stores a wrong state of membership and will not repair it:

```
Member(address = akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@H1:3000, status = Up) // ???
```

The host `H1` doesn't contain any instances of `worker`. And `> telnet H1 3000` returns `connection refused`. 
But why does the akka-cluster keep storing this wrong info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is intended, and Akka cluster in production should be run with no automatic downing, to prevent *split-brain* problems.

Imagine a two node (A and B) cluster with two client (X and Y):

- At the beginning, everything is ok and a request of `Y` connected to `B` can be forwarded to `Actor1` running on `A` for processing through remoting
- Then, because of a network partitioning,  `A` becomes unreachable from `B`, `B` might be tempted to mark `A` as down and restart `Actor1` locally.
- Client `Y` sends messages to Actor1 running on `B`
- Client `X` on the other side of network partitioning is still connected to `A` and will send messages to `Actor1`

This is a split-brain problem: the same actor with the same identifier is running on two nodes with two different states. It is very hard or impossible to rebuild the correct actor state.

To prevent this to happen, you have to pick up a reasonable downing strategy for your problem or use case:

- If you can afford it, use manual downing. An operator will recognize that the cluster is really down, and mark nodes unreachable.
- If your cluster has a dynamic number of nodes, then you need something sophisticated as the *Lightbend Split Brain Resolver*
- If your cluster is static, you can use quorum strategies to avoid split brain. You always need to run an odd number of nodes.